# U-SQL vertex graph does not show ROW_COUNT per vertex

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

U-SQL vertex graph does not show ROW_COUNT per vertex at least since Monday 17-Apr. See the pic below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. I forwarded it to the teams involved for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a regression in the EU North region (and may also happen in the other regions once the refresh rollout has completed). A file that is needed by the tool to get the row count is not being provided anymore. We are still investigating the root cause and will fix it as soon as possible for future jobs.